# How to set communication between MainActivity and a Fragment?

Tags: java, android-fragments

how can I send parameters between MainActivity and Fragment?

I already tried using getSupportFragmentManager method to do it, but it isn't working

**CODE OF IMPORTANT METHODS**

**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frag_text, createCustomFragment()).commit();
    }


}
```

**TesteFragment.java**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teste, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    EditText text = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_text);
    EditText size = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_size);

    TextView fragText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_text);

    Button changeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_change);





    return view;
}
```

**Variables status in FragmentTeste.java**

- view -> exists
- bundle -> null
- text -> null
- size -> null

Why bundle is null while I'm passing the parameters from MainActivity?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does your `createCustomFragment()` function do?

Try doing something like this:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("name",value);
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(data);
```

Comment: please, see the comment under

Answer (score 0):

My createCustomFragment method have this scope

```
private TesteFragment createCustomFragment(){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("nome", "Joao");

    TesteFragment testeFragment = new TesteFragment();

    testeFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return testeFragment;
}
```